# Mathematics puzzles

Tags: puzzle

I have a question about this math puzzle and the question offers the numbers 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10:
[image]

I already solved it:

A=4,
B=9,
C=10,
D=8,
E=7,
F=3,
G=1,
H=6,
J=5

However, it took me a while because I was trying the possibilities without a specific rule, so is there a rule to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Do not post unsearchable images of text or equations as the website's search mechanism cannot find whether it has already been asked (and answered) or will in the future.

Comment: You could just write out the system of linear equations and solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately we see that $D=8$.

Then, I think the most logical step is to try to place the $10$. It is trivially not in places $A, E, F, G, H, J$ because the minimum row and column sums fail in those cases. Thus, either $B$ or $C$ contains the $10$.

Now, $B=10 \implies H=5\implies (G,J)\in \{(1,6),(6,1),(3,4),(4,3)\}$

Using that $C+F+J=18$, $A+E+G=12$, $A+J=9$, $C+G=11$ we can show that each of these pairings break somewhere:

If $G=1$ then $C=10$ but $B=10$.

If $J=1$ then $C+F=17 \implies C,F=8,9$ but $D=8$

If $J=4$ then $C+F=14\implies C,F = 6,8$ or $9,5$ but $D=8$ and $H=5$ (also $J=4\implies A=5$)

If $G=4$ then $A+E=8\implies A,E=1,7; 2,6; 3,5$ but $C=7$; $2$ is already placed and $H=5$

So $B\neq 10 \implies C=10\implies G=1$

We can now see that:
$$A+E=11\implies A\in\{4,5,6,7\}=A_1$$
$$A+B=13\implies A\in\{4,6,7,9\}=A_2$$
$$A+J=9\implies A\in\{3,4,5,6\}=A_3; J\in \{3,4,5,6\}=J_1$$
$$F+J=8\implies J\in\{3,5\}=J_2$$
$$H+J=11\implies J\in\{4,5,6,7\}=J_3$$

I've achieved this by listing pairs and discarding any that contain $\{1,2,8,10\}$ that we have already placed.

Now: $$J_1\cap J_2\cap J_3 =\{5\}\implies J=5\implies A=4$$

and the rest fall out from there.

Comment: Thank you so much